# Problema para instalar o SciPy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

Gente estou tendo dificuldades em instalar o `scipy` pelo `pycharm` e pelo pip, estou levando as seguintes considerações ao instalar o `SciPy`

1 - É compatível com o `python 3.6`
2 - No pip digito o comando `"pip install scipy"`
3 - Todas as outras bibliotecas científicas que tentei instalar deram erro ( e acredito que seja relacionado ao `scipy`)

O erro é o seguinte:

> 1 - Failed building wheel for scipy
>   2 - Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
>   3 - Error code 1

Resumindo, preciso utilizar a biblioteca `"control 0.7.0"` para a faculdade para plotar uns gráficos, mas ela também está dando erro, gostaria de saber se esse problema relacionado as bibliotecas são particularidades dela ou eu que estou deixando passar alguma coisa? O que devo levar em consideração ao instalar um módulo? O problema pode ser com o pip?

Answer (score 2):

Boa noite. Você não disse qual sistema operacional está utilizando. Se você estiver utilizando o `Windows`, leve em consideração que o `scipy` não pode ser instalado via `pip`, pois ele não possui todas as bibliotecas necessárias. Se estiver utilizando o `windows` tente instalar a partir dos binários desta página: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy (Antes instale o `numpy` http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy).
Estes binários podem ser instalados via `pip` e `wheels`. Salve os arquivos em um diretório e faça no `prompt`:

```
pip install wheel

pip wheel --wheel-dir=/diretorio/aonde-salvou-binarios -r requirements.txt

pip install --no-index --find-links=/diretorio/aonde-salvou-binarios -r requirements.txt
```

Se você estiver utilizando mac ou linux tente atualizar a versão do pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

depois instale os pacotes

```
pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua ajuda mas pelo wheel também não deu certo, então encontrei no youtube o vídeo a seguir https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SrRh1V1Z748